# Callback for classes defined inside a Module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Ruby already has several [built-in callbacks](http://www.nach-vorne.de/2007/3/18/list-of-callback-methods/). Is there a callback for such case? Kinda like method_added, but for classes (or constants) inside a module, instead of instance methods inside a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is nothing exactly like what you're describing. However, here's how you could create your own, using `Class::inherited`.

```
module MyModule
  def self.class_added(klass)
    # ... handle it
  end
  class ::Class
    alias_method :old_inherited, :inherited
    def inherited(subclass)
      MyModule.class_added(subclass) if /^MyModule::\w+/.match subclass.name
      old_inherited(subclass)
    end
  end
end

module MyModule
  # now add classes
end
```

Comment: Yeah, patching methods to Class have its own issues. In particular, inherited will not be called on any class that defines its own callback and doesn't call super. The alternative is to alter the syntax tree with parsetree (no 1.9 on all cases for now though). But it seems that the callbacks are missing. I asked because Gregor's post is quite old, and the docs don't mention such feature.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach, by defining your own `def_class` method:

```
module M
  def self.const_missing(name)
    const_set(name, Class.new)
  end

  def self.def_class(klass, &block)
    class_added(klass.name)
    klass.class_eval(&block)
  end
end

module M
  def self.class_added(klass)
    puts "new class added: #{klass}"
  end

  def_class Hello do
    def hello
      puts "hello!"
    end
  end
end

h = M::Hello.new.hello #=> "hello!"
```

Comment: It is a good hack. With parse tree hack, it is even possible to do so without needing users to change their own modules. But parse tree hacks will introduce another scope. Or introduce another custom module-like method. Not perfect. I know Matz didn't want to add more callbacks, but some are really lacking.