# Ruby method_added callback not trigger including Modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I wanted to write a little "Deprecate-It" lib and used the "method_added" callback a lot.
But now I noticed that this callback is not triggered, when including a module.

Are there any callbacks or workarounds, to get class "Foobar" informed when somewhing is included to itself?

Small Demo to demonstrate:

```
# Including Moduls won't trigger method_added callback

module InvisibleMethod
  def invisible
    "You won't get a callback from me"
  end
end

class Foobar
  def self.method_added(m)
    puts "InstanceMethod: '#{m}' added to '#{self}'"
  end

  def visible
    "You will get a callback from me"
  end

  include InvisibleMethod
end

[:invisible, :visible, :wont_exist].each do |meth|
  puts "#{meth}: #{Foobar.public_method_defined? meth}"
end
```

That's the result:

```
InstanceMethod: 'visible' added to 'Foobar'
invisible: true
visible: true
wont_exist: false
```

Additional Information:

I really need to use a hook like method_added.

ActiveModel is adding public_instance_methods to Class during runtime though anonymous Modules.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is a good answer, but this could point you in the direction of some hacks that work.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191214/callback-for-classes-defined-inside-a-module

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that including modules doesn't add methods to the classes - it only changes the method call chain. This chain defines which classes/module will be searched for a method, that is not defined for the class in question. What happens when you include a module is an addition of an entry in that chain.

This is exactly the same as when you add a method in a superclass - this doesn't call `method_added` since it is not defined in the superclass. It would be very strange if a subclass could change the behavior of a superclass.

You could fix that by manually calling method added for an included module, by redefining `include` for your class:

```
class Foobar
  def self.include(included_module)
    included_module.instance_methods.each{|m| self.method_added(m)}
    super
  end
end
```

And it is much safer than redefining the `included` method in `Module` - the change is narrowed only to the classes, that you have defined yourself.

Comment: The method_added method is private by default, so if you want to do the inverse of this example and do the work inside the included module, you'll have to do: def self.included(base); base.send :method_added, :method_name; end

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by one of the comments, you could use some other hook to get the behavior you want. For example, try to add this at the beginning of your code:

```
class Module
  def included(klass)
    if klass.respond_to?(:method_added)
      self.instance_methods.each do |method|
        klass.method_added(method)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever a module is included in a class, all instance methods of that module will be notified to the class, as long as it defines the method `method_added`. By running your code with the change above I get this result:

```
InstanceMethod: 'visible' added to 'Foobar'
InstanceMethod: 'invisible' added to 'Foobar'
invisible: true
visible: true
wont_exist: false
```

Which I think is the behavior you want.

Comment: oh, have fun if someone doesn't call `super` when overwriting `included(klass)`

Answer (score 1):

I think `deprecation` is not big isue to require a library. it is implemented like this in `datamapper`. About `method_added` hook; it is working as expected because methods already added to `module` not `class`. Only you can get your expected result monkey patching `included` hook.

```
# got from https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/master/lib/dm-core/support/deprecate.rb
module Deprecate
  def deprecate(old_method, new_method)
    class_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
      def #{old_method}(*args, &block)
        warn "\#{self.class}##{old_method} is deprecated, use \#{self.class}##{new_method} instead (\#{caller.first})"
        send(#{new_method.inspect}, *args, &block)
      end
    RUBY
  end
end # module Deprecate

class MyClass
  extend Deprecate

  def old_method
    p "I am old"
  end
  deprecate :old_method, :new_method

  def new_method
    p "I am new"
  end
end

m = MyClass.new
m.old_method

# MyClass#old_method is deprecated, use MyClass#new_method instead (pinger.rb:27:in `<main>')
# "I am new"
```